# Algolia aroundLatLng multiple coordinates

Tags: javascript, algolia

Hey guys so I need to do a radius search around multiple coordinates, I currently have  it set up like this:

```
          params.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', '41.8781136, -87.6297982')
```

How ever I need to do something like:

```
          params.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', ['41.8781136, -87.6297982', '42.3949, -85.221212'])
```

Does this aroundLatLng property only supports 1 coordinate? is there a property that supports 2? any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to pass it an array.

There are similar method that can handle multiple location. Maybe the easiest way would be to use `insideBoundingBox` since it accepts multiple zones.
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/insideBoundingBox/